# importing messy data using R

Tags: r

Does anyone has any idea about importing the below data into R in an appropriate form? I tried strsplit function as:   `test <- strsplit(test,"[[:space:]]+")` where test is the name of the file including the following messy data. Somehow I ended up with only one character variable. I would like to have eight different variable in appropriate form. Could you please help me?

```
Black Eagles    01/12 - 12/11   1500 W  7.0 420 48  Away +3
Blue State  02/18 - 04/21   1293 L  8.0 490 48  Home +1
Hawks   01/13 - 02/17   1028 L  4.0 46  460 Away
New Apple   09/23 - 11/23   563 L   3.0 470 47  Home +2
Black White 07/05 - 09/26   713 L   5.2 500 45  Home +4
PBO 10/24 - 10/30   1495 L  1.9 47  410 Away
```

Comment: Where do these data come from? Is it possible there is a tab delimiter or similar within the original?

Comment: Yes, there are tab delimiters between each variables and spaces between two names of a variable. These are just team statistics and every column should represent a variable (9 variables). I could not figure out because this data set includes string, numeric and date variables together. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Then use `read.table(thedatafile, sep ='\t')`. Can you post the results of `dput(test)` (before you reassign the strsplit to it), and I can post a useful answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help and time. I tried read.table... function but I ended up with one variable instead of eight. The results are shown below.

Comment: > test=read.table("test.txt", sep ='\t')
> test
                                                           V1
1 Black Eagles    01/12 - 12/11   1500 W  7.0 420 48  Away +3
2     Blue State  02/18 - 04/21   1293 L  8.0 490 48  Home +1
3            Hawks   01/13 - 02/17   1028 L  4.0 46  460 Away
4     New Apple   09/23 - 11/23   563 L   3.0 470 47  Home +2
5     Black White 07/05 - 09/26   713 L   5.2 500 45  Home +4
6                PBO 10/24 - 10/30   1495 L  1.9 47  410 Away

Comment: In that case, can you copy say the first 6 lines of `test.txt` or a link to the file on the web. Edit your question to include this.

Comment: I have just copied and pasted first six rows of my data set into the question as you asked. It looks what it is in text file.

Comment: The problem is in your copying and pasting (or mine), the tab separators are being scrubbed if they ever existed at all (they will probably not be visible in most editors). A link to the file would be good.

Comment: or provide the output of `dput(readLines("test.txt", n=6))`.

Comment: I added the file on a website. Please use the link below:

Comment: https://hotfile.com/dl/179313270/8afad48/test.txt.html

Comment: There are no tabs in the data you uploaded. Since spaces are used to separate fields and as part of the team name, there is no way to separate them automatically unless you edit the file to add quotations around character fields or replace spaces between fields with commas or tabs.

Comment: column headers or names?  what is the data?  is `01/12 - 12/11` two fields or one?

Comment: Sorry for not listing before. Variables are team name, time-period,# of supporters,resultoflastgame,budget,friendshipRanking,ageSum,status,average.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**How is this?**

```
> nicelyFormatted
     [,1]           [,2]    [,3]    [,4]   [,5] [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]   [,10]
[1,] "Black Eagles" "01/12" "12/11" "1500" "W"  "7.0" "420" "48"  "Away" "+3" 
[2,] "Blue State"   "02/18" "04/21" "1293" "L"  "8.0" "490" "48"  "Home" "+1" 
[3,] "Hawks"        "01/13" "02/17" "1028" "L"  "4.0" "46"  "460" "Away" NA   
[4,] "New Apple"    "09/23" "11/23" "563"  "L"  "3.0" "470" "47"  "Home" "+2" 
[5,] "Black White"  "07/05" "09/26" "713"  "L"  "5.2" "500" "45"  "Home" "+4" 
[6,] "PBO"          "10/24" "10/30" "1495" "L"  "1.9" "47"  "410" "Away" NA
```

---

Here is the code that was used to get the above table:

```
library(stringr)

# Open Connection to file
pathToFile <- path.expand("~/path/to/file/myfile.txt")
f <- file(pathToFile, "rb")  

# Read in lines
rawText <- readLines(f)


# Find the dahses
dsh <- str_locate_all(rawText, " - ")

# Splice, using the dashes as a guide
lng <- length(rawText)
spliced <- sapply(1:lng, function(i) 
  spliceOnDash(rawText[[i]], dsh[[c(i, 1)]], dsh[[c(i, 2)]])
)

# make it purtty
nicelyFormatted <- formatNicely(spliced)
nicelyFormatted


#-------------------#
#    FUNCTIONS      #
#-------------------#


spliceOnDash <- function(strn, start, end)  {

  # split around the date
  pre <- substr(strn, 1, start-6)
  dates <- substr(strn, start-5, end+5)
  post <- substr(strn, end+6, str_length(strn))

  # Clean up
  pre <- str_trim(pre)

  # replace all double spaces with single spaces
  while(str_detect(post, "  ")) {
    post <- str_replace_all(str_trim(post), "  ", " ")    
  }

  # splice on space
  post <- str_split(post, " ")

  # if dates are one field, remove this next line
  dates <- str_split(dates, " - ")

  # return
  c(unlist(pre), unlist(dates), unlist(post))
}

# Function to clean up the list into a nice table
formatNicely <- function(spliced)  {
  lngst <- max(sapply(spliced, length))
  t(sapply(spliced, function(x)  
      if(length(x) < lngst) c(x, rep(NA, lngst-length(x))) else x ))
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks everyone, especially RS.